# Spark DataFrame write to JDBC - Can't get JDBC type for array<array<int>>

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to save a dataframe via JDBC (to postgres). One of the fields is of type `Array[Array[Int]]`. Without any casting, it fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't 
get JDBC type for array<array<int>>
    at ... (JdbcUtils.scala:148)
```

I added explicit casting to the array datatype to guide the transformation:

```
  val df = readings
    .map { case ((a, b), (_, d, e, arrayArrayInt)) => (a, b, d, e, arrayArrayInt) }
    .toDF("A", "B", "D", "E", "arrays")
  edgesDF
    .withColumn("arrays_", edgesDF.col("arrays").cast(ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType))))
    .drop("arrays")
    .withColumnRenamed("arrays_", "arrays")
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.ErrorIfExists)
    .jdbc(url = dbURLWithSchema, table = "mytable", connectionProperties = dbProps)
```

But it still fails with the same exception.

How can I get this data to persist to DB?

Comment: I know this was a while ago but did you ever discover a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can store `array<array<int>>` in database, it doesn't supports datatype as array

One option is to make a single string with delimiter by using a simple `udf` as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val arrToString = udf((value: Seq[Seq[Int]]) => {
  value.map(x=> x.map(_.toString).mkString(",")).mkString("::")
})

// this udf creates  array<array<int>> to string as 1,2,3::3,4,5::6,7

df.withColumn("eventTime", arrToString($"eventtime"))
```

Hipe this helps!

Comment: Postgres supports arrays.

Comment: @philantrovert sorry didnot see the postgres in the question before