# How to insert a data frame which has a column array<array<double>> in Postgresql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to store a dataframe with a nested schema in Postgresql. Can someone please help me and explain how to store the columns (coordinates) and (user_mentions) in Postgres? I've read that postgres can store array type but I'm getting an error when trying to write to the DB . I'm not entirely sure if my table is created correctly.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<array<double>>
```

DataFrame Schema:

```
root
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_status_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweet_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- reply_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- user_mentions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Postgres Table Creation:

```
create table test-table (created_at varchar, id int, text text, source text, user_id int, in_reply_to_status_id varchar, in_reply_to_user_id int, lang varchar, retweet_count int, reply_count int, coordinates double precision[][], hashtags text[], user_mentions text[]);
```

Spark Scala Code:

```
   val df_1 = df.select(col("created_at"), col("id"), col("text"), col("source"), col("user.id").as("user_id"),
      col("in_reply_to_status_id"), col("in_reply_to_user_id"),
      col("lang"), col("retweet_count"), col("reply_count"), col("place.bounding_box.coordinates"),
      col("entities.hashtags"), col("entities.user_mentions")).withColumn("coordinates", explode(col("coordinates")))

    df_1.show(truncate = false)
    df_1.printSchema()

    df_1.write
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "postgres_url")
      .option("dbtable", "xxx.mytable")
      .option("user", "user")
      .option("password", "pass")
      .save()
```

Sample Input:

Coordinates Column:

```
[[80.063341, 26.348309], [80.063341, 30.43339], [88.2027, 30.43339], [88.2027, 26.348309]]
```

User_Mentions:

```
[[123456789, 123456789, [0, 15], Name, ScreenName]]
```

Comment: linking an unanswered old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563340/spark-dataframe-write-to-jdbc-cant-get-jdbc-type-for-arrayarrayint

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark has only support for reading and writing single dimension arrays with JDBC. You can convert your data to have more than one row (i.e. `explode` it to have double[] in multiple rows) or you can convert your data from `double[][]` to a comma-separated `string[]` or plain `string`.

e.g. `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` can be converted to `["1,2", "3,4"]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I went with the second option of converting the data into comma-separated string.